# Limit Google News RSS to specific country

Tags: google-news

This may well be documented somewhere obvious, but I'm not seeing it. I'm parsing Google News results from RSS, but I'm struggling to get the RSS feed to match what I'm seeing online, with results limited to my country.

I'm in South Africa. To see SA news on a topic, I search for the topic in Google News, then select "Pages from South Africa" in the left menu. Although that option is under "The web", it does limit the news results as well.

However, the RSS link in the page footer goes to the generic (ie: not region-specific) news results as if I hadn't selected "pages from..." at all. I've been playing with the parameters in the feed URL, but I haven't found any way to get it to restrict the RSS results to my region. (Similarly: can't find an option to limit a CSE - custom search engine - the same way).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Update: looks like it can't be done - the RSS URL doesn't obey the same rules as the regular searches ("&cr=countryZA"). Manipulating the query string to get the result, and scraping the results out, is in defiance of Google's Ts&Cs.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `&geo=usa` or even use zip code like `&geo=99553`

Answer (score -1):

It can be done like so: https://news.google.com/news/feeds?country=AU?geo=2000

The above URL would limit the RSS output to news in Sydney, Australia.

Comment: Why the downvote? This still seems like a valid solution that answers the question?