# What's the meaning of "ceid" in Google News url

Tags: web-scraping

I am recently working on web scraping of Google News and dealing with the URL format. I have same question of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792590/google-news-xml-api-use-country-language-parameters) about the meaning of ceid.

For example the link from the post: https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=studie&hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de

I know hl = host language, gl = for the search results whose country of origin matches the parameter value, but I can't find what ceid for. If I cut that part of the search link, it is unable to show the result, so obviously it is a must part.

So what's the meaning and the purpose of the "ceid"?

Many thanks.

Comment: it's a good question. Should be answered by Google..., but it does not appear to be a necessary field. Yet, I'll include it anyway.

Comment: @jsfa11, I did some searching in Google but it doesn't explain clearly.

Comment: It's refer to country and language another uris like your uri

https://news.google.com/topstories?ceid=US:en&gl=US&hs=es-es&pz=1&hl=en-US
 - and 
https://news.google.com/foryou?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

Answer (score 1):

It might mean the country name and show the results according to the common language of the country.

For example:  'ceid=IN:en' means the country as "India", and hence the result should show up in English.